# Google Analytics - Can I use it to track multiple subdomains of a domain I don't have access to?

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, domain-masking

the title question is pretty much self explanatory:
I am working on a customer support portal for a company who bought an external platform for this purpose. Now, each of the five languages has its own independent URL, but we set up a redirection so that each language now has a link which looks like the sub-domain of our company's website.

So let's say that we have:

```
www.companyswebsite.com
```

and 5 language portals:

```
www.en.externalplatform.com;
www.fr.externalplatform.com;
www.it.externalplatform.com;
www.de.externalplatform.com;
www.es.externalplatform.com;
```

masked now as:

```
www.en.companyswebsite.com;
www.fr.companyswebsite.com;
(...)
```

I can't control my Company's website, but I can control all of the subdomains.

Is there any possibility to track the subdomains with Analytics?

Many thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is described [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#twoSubDirectories) under **Tracking Across Two Sub-directories on the Same Domain**

Comment: I don't think so. That's different paths names not different hostnames.